# Winforms Data binding

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I'm familiar with WPF technology, specifically MVVM methodology. Recently I began to program in Winforms, and I was wondering- Does using data-binding in winforms (combined with INotiify...) is considered the best practice, or is it an overkill?

Some people say that data-binding is a real pain in the ass in winforms, is that right?

And just to make it clear: I'm not talking about full MVVM implementation in winforms- simply binding data to controls (text boxes and such, not buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data binding in Windows Forms works very differently than WPF - and is (IMO) a bit more of a pain.  The main issues are there are more [restrictions on the binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3y6cb0c.aspx), and there isn't a clean way to handle things like `IValueConverter`, so there is typically a lot of extra work involved in getting anything but very simply binding to work cleanly.

Details on how to use data binding in Windows Forms are described on [MSDN in Windows Forms Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx).